# Dropbox HTTP API v2 overwrite files when moving them

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the `/files/move` endpoint on Dropbox API v2, but getting the error that a file of the same name exists in the destination directory (which it does).

How can I set the HTTP request to simply override the existing file with the file being moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got confirmation from Dropbox that overwrite is not possible for the `/files/move` endpoint (at this time).

> The API doesn't currently offer mode options like this (e.g., to force an overwrite) for the copy and move endpoints, so you'll need to delete the existing file first. We'll consider this a feature request though.